# Como enviar várias strings por url no Android studio?

Tags: android

Tenho dados para enviar para um servidor web, o servidor recebe as strings seguindo esse padrão:

http://teste.com/{id}/{latitude}/{longitude}

Como faço para enviar esses dados ocupando esses espaços de uma só vez pelo Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Simples:

```
String url = "http://teste.com/pagina?id=" + id + "&latitude=" + latitude + "&longitude=" + longitude;
```

Depois do lado do servidor:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
```

Esta página do [android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#java) ensina a fazer algo semelhante usando volley, mas eu faria isso usando POST em vez de GET por questões de segurança, já que é enviado pela url pode ter seus dados alterados, mais informações [página w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo muito o uso do [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) para consumir APIs

```
interface TesteService{
    @GET("{id}/{latitude}/{longitude}"
    Call<Objeto> getObject(@Path("id") String id,
                           @Path("latitude") String latitude,
                           @Path("longitude") String longitude);
}

public class TesteRetrofit{
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://teste.com/")
        .build();
    TesteService tService = retrofit.create(TesteService.class);

    public Objeto pegarObjeto(){
     return tService.getObject("123","20°34'07.2\"S","43°48'44.6\"W").execute().body();
    }
}
```

Esse é um exemplo básico de código, sugiro da uma lida na [documentação](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) para saber mais.

Esse código vai lançar a excepção `I/O on UIThread` se executado na Thread principal do Android